# No mapping found for HTTP Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm doing a little demo with spring mvc and I have a problem when deploying the application. I'm using wildfly 10.0.0

In don't understand what is happening

in My web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>simu-cmac</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>simu-cmac</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in my app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cmac.simu" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

And my Controller

```
@Controller
public class SimuAPIController {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping("/home.htm")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.info("Returning home view");
    System.out.println("To home view");
    return new ModelAndView("home.jsp");
}

}
```

When the application is deployed the following error is displayed on the console

```
19:50:39,417 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-3) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/simu-cmac/home.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'simu-cmac'
```

Comment: can you try it in tomcat? I just want to make sure whether it is the application server's problem.

Comment: just try /home.htm. I couldn`t see context path set for /simu-cmac/home.htm?

Comment: I deployed it in tomcat and ran without problems, someone knows why wildfly gives those problems
I havnt changed anything in configuration or code, only the server

Answer (score 0):

It seems may be your controller is not scaned by spring application. As you defined :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cmac.simu" />
```

So your controller must be inside `com.cmac.simu` package. So spring config can scan your controller.